# How do I pass arguments to map in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to write a small function to add a value to a list. it looks like this:

`(defvar fares '(31.14 28.12 25.10 22.08 19.06 16.04 13.02 10))`

`(defun plus-extra (fare) (+ 3.02 fare))`

`(map 'plus-extra fares)`

Fairly predictably, the elisp barfs because the function needs an argument.  What am I missing?

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function which doesn't have enough argument here is `map`, not the one you defined.

The `map` function does not exists in Emacs Lisp, it is provided by the `cl` package. This `map` function require 3 arguments, the first one must be the type of what `map` should return. This:

```
(map 'list 'plus-extra fares)
```

will work. But what you want is this:

```
(mapcar 'plus-extra fares)
```

which is native elisp.

PS: Don't forget that Emacs comes with its documentation! <kbd>C-h f map RET</kbd> ;-).

Comment: With partial function application: (mapcar (apply-partially '+ 3.02) fares)

Answer (score 7):

Use `mapcar`, not `map`. With `mapcar`, your example yields:

```
(34.160000000000004 31.14 28.12 25.099999999999998 22.08 19.06 16.04 13.02)
```

If you `M-x describe-function RET map RET`, you'll see the signature of `map` is not what you expected:

```
(map TYPE FUNCTION SEQUENCE...)

Map a FUNCTION across one or more SEQUENCEs, returning a sequence.
TYPE is the sequence type to return.
```